# how to identify the number of value 1 per three columns

Tags: matlab

I am trying to identify the consecutive three-column groups that have >2 instances of "1" in this matrix.

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0;
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0]
```

Can anyone help?

For example, columns 1-3 have 4 instances of "1" (which is >2); columns 2-4 have only 2 instances of "1" (not >2); columns 3-5 have 3 instances of "1" (>2).  None of the remaining three-column groups have >2 instances of "1". So the desired results would be

```
[1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ... ]
```

Comment: Huh? I'm baffled by your question. Please restate it.

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono: As you already posted an input matrix, you can also post the wanted result. I think the result can be computed in one line, but we need either the input/output relation or an **exact** statement, what to compute.

Comment: @Mehrwolf: actually, i just want to identify if there has (sum of element which has value "1" more than 2 or not per three column). if yes, i want the output is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one line solution:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0;
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0];

found = conv(sum(A ==1), [1 1 1], 'valid') > 2
```

Result:

```
found =

     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: actually, i just want to identify if there has sum of element which has value "1" more than 2 or not per three column. so i want the output is "found" or not.

Comment: Edited to a one liner without loops - if it is correct let me know and I'll add an explanation if you need

Answer (score 5):

**Rephrasing the question:**
You want to know, if the number of matrix elements with value 1 in three adjacent columns is larger than 2.

Let's suppose, you have a matrix

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0;
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 0]
```

You can easily compare, if the elements fulfill some condition, using a binary operator, e.g. let's test, if a matrix element is equal to 1:

```
A == 1
ans =
     1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

The result is a matrix of `true` and `false` values. However, you can even sum these values and they will be promoted to floating point numbers, automatically.

```
numOnesPerColumn = sum(A==1)
numOnesPerColumn =
     2  1  1  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

You see, the result is a vector that holds for every column the number of elements, which
are equal to 1. The only task left is to find out, if the sum of three consecutive numbers is larger than 2. This can be done in quite some ways, e.g.

```
numOnesIn3Columns = arrayfun(@(x) sum(numOnesPerColumn(x:x+2)), ...
                             1 : length(numOnesPerColumn) - 2);
```

Another approach using a loop (probably easier to write for Matlab beginners):

```
numOnesIn3Columns = zeros(1, length(numOnesPerColumn) - 2);
for column = 1 : length(numOnesPerColumn) - 2
    numOnesIn3Columns(column) = sum(numOnesPerColumn(column : column + 2));
end
```

Or you can also do

```
numOnesIn3Columns = filter(ones(1,3), 1, numOnesPerColumn);
numOnesIn3Columns = numOnesIn3Columns (1:end-2);
```

The result is for all cases a vector containing the sum of three consecutive elements:

```
numOnesIn3Columns =
     4  2  3  2  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

So, in which columns are more than two one-elements? We can easily find the column number
of the first of these columns by doing

```
find(numOnesIn3Columns > 2)
ans =
     1  3
```

Ok, columns 1--3 and 3--5 violate your constraints. And how many ones are actually in these columns?

```
numOnesIn3Columns(find(numOnesIn3Columns > 2))
ans =
     4  3
```

So columns 1--3 have 4 ones and columns 3--5 have 3 ones.